# parsing XML: unbound prefix error

Tags: xml

My XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<EditText xlmns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/field"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
androud:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:sineLine="false"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What is wrong with it? The error:Error parsing XML: unbound prefix shows up!

Comment: fixed but the error is still there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two typos:

1. You've spelled `xmlns` as `xlmns` on the `EditText` element.
2. The penultimate use of the `android` prefix is spelled `androud`

The following snippet corrects both problems:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/field" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:sineLine="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

On a related note, consider using a tool that provides better error messages. These typos were made obvious by the tool I used to validate your XML (RAD 7.5.5.3):

- The prefix "androud" for attribute "androud:layout_height" associated
  with an element type "EditText" is not bound.
- The prefix "xlmns" for attribute "xlmns:android" associated with an element type "EditText" is not bound.

Comment: god...this is ...i can't even tell.I don't even want to imagine what will happen if I don't see these typos in a long code...