# Error parsing XML: unbound prefix with Toolbar sdk 21

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-5.0-lollipop

So, I installed the latest SDK 21 Lollipop release. I was having the actionbar activated with icons on in, and I am trying to recover it back using the new toolbar feature... but it seems not working properly. Basically I am following the information provided [here](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/)

Basically, you need to create a toolbar instance in the layout. So did I:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
   android:id="@+id/myapp_toolbar"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:minHeight="20"
   android:background="@drawable/action_bar_myapp" />
```

However, this is creating and error message at the second line with the error message "error: Error parsing XML unbound prefix".

When this error is happening (like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796293/parsing-xml-unbound-prefix-error)) is usually due to having a wrong sintax, I copied/pasted directiyl from the webpage, also I made a simple test. By removing all android tags, the problem is still present.

Probably is something very simple, but I am stucked. Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to declare the android namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
   ....
/>
```